How to remove a single script from wp_options in WordPress Database
I am just joining a wordpress project and my client would like the zendesk messaging widget removed from their website.  After searching for the script in the file manager I figured out that the script was added to wp_options table in the sql database.  On our staging site I removed just this script from that row in wp_options but it still shows up.  How do I successfully remove just a single script from a row in wp_options and have it actually stop showing up?
I would include the entire row here but its extremely long so it would go over my limit.  I'm happy to share any additional details as needed.  I havn't worked on many WordPress projects so I'm not familiar with wp_options and the info needed to manipulate them.
This is the widget I am attempting to remove:
<!-- Start of infinitecbdhelp Zendesk Widget script --><script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=""> </script><!-- End of infinitecbdhelp Zendesk Widget script -->


If that script is showing up in the DB like an entry (and it would be helpful if you included what the 'key' was and not just the 'value') then there's got to be somewhere that you can enter a script into a field that gets added to the site.  Check for plugins like WP Code Lite and look to see if the theme itself has an 'add code' setting/fields.  Also, there could be a function in the theme that checks if this record is in the database and if it isn't it just adds it again - not sure why someone would do it this way, at all, but it's feasible.
